# Minhag to say Mizmor Shir L'Yom Hashabbos twice

Tags: sources-mekorot, shabbat, minhag

I recently read in a sefer that there was a minhag to say mizmor shir lyom hashabbos twice in the kehilla of the Maharal by kabbalos shabbos.

The reason why it was said twice is based on a story about the golem of the Maharal. The legend has it that the Maharal forgot to remove the Shem HaShem before shabbos and realized right after he said mizmor shir and already accepted shabbos. He didn't want the golem to function on shabbos ,so he went to be matir neder for accepting shabbos by mistake. He then removed the shem from the golem and then recited mizmor shir a second time to accept shabbos again.

This story was said in the name of the Eshel Avraham (M'buchach). I looked around in his comments on the Shulchan Aruch and could not find such a story. Anyone know where this story can be found in his actual works?

- The focus of the question is where this source can be found . The question of whether the Maharal actually created a golem is not part of the question or discussion.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/32173/759

Comment: Any source that points to the Eshel Avraham ,didn't see any

Comment: What book did you find this in?

Comment: I doubt the Eishel Avraham said this because, as you alluded to, the Maharal didn't create a Gollem, and no one suggested he did until the late 1800s

Comment: @robev there are slightly older sources, but still 19th century. See here: https://jqr.pennpress.org/media/23891/JQRnewArticle.pdf

Comment: Shir quotes the legend from המגידים בעלטה את השמועה המתפשטת בין אוהבי גוזמאות https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6757&st=&pgnum=53

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's found in the work *[Birkat Avraham](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30936&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=)* (published 1887), which contains teachings of R. Avraham David of Buchach (author of *Eshel Avraham*) as recorded by his student R. Moshe Dov of Kolomea.

The piece you're looking for starts at the bottom of [page 11a](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30936&st=&pgnum=21).

Comment: The piece also contains the legend that the *altneuschul* in Prague is so named because it contains stones from Jerusalem, and was therefore built on condition (*al tenai*) that when the Messiah arrives, the synagogue be dismantled and the stones returned.

Comment: Thank you !......